# PhantomJS - connect to GhostDriver error

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am scraping websites with PhantomJS and Selenium. My problem is that after about 50 checked URLs i have an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to GhostDriver

I have not any idea how to fix it, i tried two PhantomJS versions (1.9 and 1.98) and it does not work still. Have You any idea?

Here is the code I'm executing:

```
def get_car_price(self, car_url): 
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe') 
    browser.get(car_url) 
    content = browser.page_source 
    browser.quit() 

    website = lh.fromstring(content) 
    for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.car_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'): 
        return price.text
```

Comment: Show us some code please and a complete error traceback. Thanks.

Comment: `def get_car_price(self, car_url):
        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe')
        browser.get(car_url)
        content = browser.page_source
        browser.quit()
        website = lh.fromstring(content)
        for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.car_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'):
            return price.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of opening/quitting the `PhantomJS` browser, keep it open and reuse it. Create it globally at the startup of your script and quit when script is about to finish.

Example:

```
class Service(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe') 

    def get_car_price(self, car_url): 
        self.browser.get(car_url) 
        content = self.browser.page_source 

        website = lh.fromstring(content) 
        for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.car_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'): 
            return price.text

    def shutdown(self):
        self.browser.quit() 

service = Service()
try:
    for url in urls:
        print(service.get_car_price(url))
finally:
    service.shutdown()
```

Comment: What could be the reason? Out of memory to start another PhantomJS instance?

Comment: @ArtjomB. not sure, I think it has smth to do with quickly stopping/starting the service and the [way the process is started on windows](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py#70). Anyway, the workaround I'm suggesting would also positively affect performance, so, may be not knowing is good here :)